# how to set popup background color to transparent

Tags: qt, qml, qtquickcontrols2

I have the following popup to appear when the game finishes:

```
Popup {
    id: popup
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    Text{
        text: "Game Over!!" + "\n\n" + "New High Score: "+ score_val
        anchors.centerIn: canvas
        color: "grey"
        font.pixelSize: 70
        font.family: gill.name
    }
    modal: true
    focus: true
    closePolicy: Popup.CloseOnEscape | Popup.CloseOnPressOutsideParent

}
```

It's all good but the background is white and there seems no background color property, what should I do?

Comment: The button that allows you to create publications says "Ask Question", does not say "Ask Questions" so if you have several problems then create several posts. On the other hand, tags such as "qml" should not be in the title since this is the tag section. And finally: Popup does not exist in Qt Quick Controls 1 but in Qt Quick Controls 2 so you must use the qtquickcontrols2 tag for future readers to easily find your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set an item as a [`background`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-popup.html#background-prop) property:

```
Popup {
    id: popup
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    Text{
        text: "Game Over!!" + "\n\n" + "New High Score: "+ score_val
        anchors.centerIn: canvas
        color: "grey"
        font.pixelSize: 70
        font.family: gill.name
    }
    background: Rectangle {
        color: "transparent"
        border.color: "black"
    }
    modal: true
    focus: true
    closePolicy: Popup.CloseOnEscape | Popup.CloseOnPressOutsideParent
}
```

Comment: Or just set it to empty `Item{}` if no border is required